# Can AngularJS directives and scope variables be simplified

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Senario**

I want to write a simple Angular directive that has a directive name (as an attribute) that can be used as a variable as well (ie. data-directive-name="some value" where we can use "some value" in the directive's scope).

**HTML**

```
<span data-gender="controller.model.gender"></span>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
.directive('gender', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div>{{ gender }}</div>',
        scope: {
           gender: '='
        }
    };
})
```

**Expected result**

```
<span data-gender="M">
    <div>M</div>
</span>
```

**Actual Result**

```
<span data-gender="M"></span>
```

Comment: It works fine in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g44f8mnp/)

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? This works in a fiddle that was posted in the comments. Try:
scope: { gender: '=gender' }

Comment: might be version specific, try just gender instead of data-gender